# Private information in BSOD *.dmp files

Tags: windows, server-crashes, bsod

Does BSOD dmp files contain any private information (keys, passwords, etc)? Can they be shared without any risk of vulnurabillity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [core dump](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) file contains a recording of the memory state of your application/OS/kernel at the time it crashed.

The blue screen of death creates a kernel memory dump that can and will contain data relevant to whatever applications were running at the time the crash happened and may indeed contain private data such as clear text passwords, private keys etc. that were stored in memory.